Clarification Needed: Why My Linear Programming Duality Proof Incorrectly Treats Inequalities as Equalities
\begin{align*}
\max \{ c^\top x \mid Ax \leq b, x \geq 0 \} &\leq \min \{ y^\top b \mid y^\top A \geq c^\top, y \geq 0 \} \\
&\leq \max \{ y^\top b \mid y^\top A \geq c^\top, y \geq 0 \} \\
&\leq \min \{ c^\top x \mid Ax \geq b, x \leq 0 \} \\
&\leq \max \{ c^\top x \mid Ax \geq b, x \leq 0 \} \\
&\leq \min \{ y^\top b \mid y^\top A \leq c^\top, y \leq 0 \} \\
&\leq \max \{ y^\top b \mid y^\top A \leq c^\top, y \leq 0 \} \\
&\leq \min \{ c^\top x \mid Ax \leq b, x \geq 0 \} \\
&\leq \max \{ c^\top x \mid Ax \leq b, x \geq 0 \}.
\end{align*}
By using weak duality and complementary slackness the above holds for arbitrary $ n, m \in \mathbb{N} $, $ A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} $, $ b \in \mathbb{R}^m $, $ c \in \mathbb{R}^n $ for which the minima and maxima exist.
The inequalities are all equalities and it does not make a difference whether to mimimise or maximise, but it is impossible. Can someone tell me which step is incorrect?

Why is it impossible?
